# React route несколько компонентов в одном path?

Tags: reactjs, route

Есть несколько компонентов (about, skill, story).
Мне необходимо рендерить их при клике на Link="/main", как лучше это все организовать?
Есть идея создать отдельный компонент MainPage.js импортировать туда все нужные мне компоненты, а затем создать Route component="MainPage". Хотелось бы услышать ваши варианты, спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можешь создать отдельный компонент ... Зависит от того чё ты хочешь.
С рута, а потом в Mainpage Switch

```js
<Route path = `${match.path}/main_page` component={MainPage} />
<Switch>
<Route path = exact `${match.path}/some_path` component={Component} />
<Route path = exact `${match.path}/some_path2` component={Component2} />
</Switch>
```

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. На данный момент я использовал `<Route path="/" exact render={(props) => (<Fragment> <About /> <Skill /> <Experience /> </Fragment> )}/>`

Comment: @Shakhzod Yokubov render не используйте так, у вас же все отрендерится на одной странице, а вы хотите на разных. И Fragment если рассматривать Ваш случай) можно заменить на <> <About>....</>  Отметьте вопрос решенным.

Comment: Так мне и нужно было отрендерить <About /> <Skill /> <Experience /> компоненты на одной страничке, а <Projects /> на другой, в итоге у меня вышло `<BrowserRouter>
        <Header />
        <Route
          path="/"
          exact
          render={(props) => (
            <Fragment>
              <About />
              <Skill />
              <Experience />
            </Fragment>
          )}
        />
        <Route path="/projects" exact component={Projects} />
      </BrowserRouter>`